# ASP.NET Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] <<< gives the "physical" connection IP?

Tags: asp.net

Ignoring other possiblities such as `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`, does `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` gives me the "principal" IP of the client?

I'm talking about the IP that made the actual TCP connection.
Will `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` always be the "real" IP address of the remote endpoint?

Just to clarify: Even if it's a proxy who made the real TCP connection I'd like have its IP, and not a forwarded one.

Comment: If HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is missing then chances are yes.  It is possible to have a proxy server which does not abide by adding a HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR (by design or configuration) and ssh tunneling obviously does not add this header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REMOTE_ADDR` variable will be the IP of the system that directly connected to your web server to request the URL; so it would be the forward-most proxy server, if there is a proxy server.

Comment: Concise answer, backing up several things I've already read. As for your comments regarding my vague question, I want the IP that my server sees, that's it, doesn't matter how many NATs/Proxies it is behind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, except if its been through a NAT firewall.  A NAT firewalled address would be masquerading many 192.168.x.x or any other private subnet behind a public IP address.  So you'd be looking at the IP address of the NAT firewall (i.e. a Linksys Router or what have you).

Be warned that many cell phone carriers have HUGE NAT networks so they always look like they are coming from one or two public IP addresses.

Comment: A NAT firewall being at the client location would not have any effect on what IP is reported via `REMOTE_ADDR` when there is a proxy server downstream; it will still be the proxy server's IP that is reported. In fact, in this regard, a proxy server and traditional NAT device have the same effect here: You get the IP of the 'closest' thing to the server.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying this answer is incorrect at all - I just think the question was a little vague as far as what information is actually desired by the asker; does he *want* the 'original' client IP (even if it's a private one), or does he want the proxy address?

Comment: Yeah when I was answering this I was thinking that with the "ignoring possibilities" clause really the only other thing would be a NAT firewall.  I had thought that there was the possibility of a program running on someone's local box that they wanted their server to connect back to and with the NAT firewall if it didn't have port forwarding enabled... no dice.